# column definition for maxmind geolite city ipv6 csv file

Tags: csv, ipv6, maxmind

I am trying to use the the maxmind geolite city ipv6 data for an application. The file can be downloaded from here [maxmind-website](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCityv6-beta/GeoLiteCityv6.csv.gz) . Unfortunately, the column headers are missing on this file.

Does anyone know what these headers are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a response from Maxmind thru a chat with Paul
Here are the header details.
startIP, endIP, startIPnumeric, endIPnumeric, country code, region code, city name, lat, long, postal code, metro code, area code.

However, Paul from Maxmind suggested to use [geolite2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) which contains data for both ipv6 and ipv4. This seems to be helpful